# can i retrieve fact's value after searching for it? Clips

Tags: clips

I know how to search to check whether fact slot exists, I need to know how to obtain the value of other slots in that fact

```
  (deftemplate details
(slot name(type STRING))(slot occ (type STRING))......)
and 
(deffacts details
    (details (occ "student")(name "mike"))
    (details (occ "professor")(name "john"))
   .......
)
```

(defrule search

(userinfo(occ?occ))
   (details(occ?occ) )

```
 =>
```

?????????????????????????
  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind them in the conditions of the rule:

```
(defrule search
   (userinfo (occ ?occ)) 
   (details (occ ?occ) (name ?name))
   =>
   (printout t "Name is " ?name crlf))
```